# use of unassigned local variable 'bytes'

Tags: c#

```
Byte[] bytes;

string qry = "SELECT seller.sid,seller.fname, seller.img, seller.lname, seller.contact, seller.emailid, login.status FROM seller INNER JOIN login ON seller.lid = login.lid where login.status =1 and seller.img=@Data";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;

if (bytes == null) {
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("noimg.jpg");
}
```

How can I show `noimg.jpg` in the `img` column when it is `null`? Im trying to do it by this way but it's *not working*. What I can do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I suggest declaring `byte[] bytes` as close as possible to its usage:

```
// do not declare any local variable prematurely: do we want bytes here? No

// Make query readable: it helps to see that filtering (where) is very strange
string qry = 
  @"SELECT seller.sid,
           seller.fname, 
           seller.img, 
           seller.lname, 
           seller.contact, 
           seller.emailid, 
           login.status 
      FROM seller INNER JOIN 
           login ON seller.lid = login.lid 
     WHERE login.status = 1 AND 
           seller.img = @Data"; // filtering on IMAGE?!! Very dubiuos solution 

// wrap IDisposable (SqlCommand) into using
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con)) {
  // And here we want byte[] bytes as a storage for the image:
  byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("noimg.jpg");

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler wants you to provide value to  variable before you use it,

```
Byte[] bytes = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise byte array to avoid error because you are using it before assigning value to it.

```
Byte[] bytes = null;
```

But this will always pass null value to your query. Instead populate byte array first and then pass as parameter to your query.

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("noimg.jpg");;
string qry = "SELECT seller.sid,seller.fname, seller.img, seller.lname, seller.contact, seller.emailid, login.status FROM seller INNER JOIN login ON seller.lid = login.lid where login.status =1 and seller.img=@Data";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
```